# Powershell sorting columns

Tags: sql, powershell

I was able to sort the column and remove duplicates using -Unique

```
Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Header $h | sort id -Unique
```

My problem is that I can't remove a specific row using the status property

| ID | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Current |
| 1 | John | Future |
| 2 | Mary | Future |
| 2 | Mary | Notice |
| 3 | Paul | Future |

I want the rows to be unique by status order.

1. Current
2. Notice
3. Future

Example: If there's no Current but have Notice and Future, Notice will be selected.

| ID | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Current |
| 2 | Mary | Notice |
| 3 | Paul | Future |

Would you please let me know what I need to add on my script?

Comment: If the sort order is `Current > Notice > Future` then why you're showing us `Mary > Future` when we can see that she has `Notice` from your input. That's not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake. that should be Notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746651/powershell-sorting-columns#comment121496764_68747058) for the more clever approach (*as always hehe*):

```
Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Header $h |
Sort-Object { @{ Current = 0; Notice = 1; Future = 2}[$_.Status] } |
Sort-Object ID -Unique
```

---

<strike>Try with this:</strike>

```
Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Header $h |
Sort-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Current' }, { $_.Status -eq 'Notice' } -Descending |
Sort-Object ID -Unique
```

Assuming the sort priority is **Current > Notice > Future**, I think this should work, though I'm not sure if it's possible to do it on one go, as you can see I'm pipping `Sort-Object` to `Sort-Object` again. Would love to know if it's possible to sort and get unique on one go.

```
$csv = @'
ID  Name    Status
1   John    Current
1   John    Future
2   Mary    Future
2   Mary    Notice
3   Paul    Future
4   TestUser    Notice
4   TestUser    Future
4   TestUser    Current
5   TestUser2   Notice
5   TestUser2   Current
'@ -replace ' +',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Use this (much better):
$csv | Sort-Object { @{ Current = 0; Notice = 1; Future = 2}[$_.Status] } |
Sort-Object ID -Unique

$csv | Sort-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Current' },
                   { $_.Status -eq 'Notice' } -Descending |
       Sort-Object ID -Unique
```

This results in:

```
ID Name      Status 
-- ----      ------ 
1  John      Current
2  Mary      Notice 
3  Paul      Future 
4  TestUser  Current
5  TestUser2 Current
```

Comment: FYI, you can replace your `-replace`  by importing from CSV and specifying tab delimiter directly like this: ` ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `

Comment: @SagePourpre yup, I just copy pasted OP's table to my code and added those test users hence why I'm using the replace there. But you're totally right if the CSV was export like that.

Comment: Kudos for the clever chaining of the `Sort-Object` calls. Note that you could simplify to `$csv | Sort-Object { @{ Current = 0; Notice = 1; Future = 2}[$_.Status] } | Sort-Object ID -Unique`

Comment: @mklement0 I knew there was a more clever way of doing it, you're always surprising me!